# confused with linear gradient

Tags: css, sass, colors, material-ui, gradient

I couldn't remake the gradient with CSS :
So here is the objective :
[image]

More information
Gradient color:
Start color: #1696B6 with 50% opacity
End color: Black with 100% transparency

[image]

I already tried. I got this :
$gradiant-background-dark-theme: linear-gradient(#1696b6, black, #1696b6);
[image]
I need someone to help me.

```css
.gradient{
  height:200px;
  width:400px;
  background: linear-gradient(#1696b6, black, #1696b6)
}
```

```html
<div class='gradient'>test</div>
```

Comment: Could you put your code into your question - in particular is that the overall layout you are looking for? I ask because it looks more like a pale blue fading to transparent over a fairly (but not completely) black background rather than becoming black at the end.

Comment: okay I will put it in the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the perfect matching

```
$gradiant-background-dark-theme: repeating-linear-gradient(to top,rgb(22, 150, 180) 0%,rgb(0, 0, 0,0.5) 10%,rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 90%,rgb(22, 150, 182) 100%)
```

```css
.container {
background: black;
}
.gradient{
  height:200px;
  width:400px;
  background: repeating-linear-gradient(to top,rgb(22, 150, 180) 0%,rgb(0, 0, 0,0.5) 10%,rgb(0, 0, 0, 0.5) 90%,rgb(22, 150, 182) 100%)


}
```

```html
<div class='container'><div class='gradient'>test</div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use Angles in your CSS
instead of this

```
$gradiant-background-dark-theme: linear-gradient(#1696b6, black, #1696b6);
```

Please Use

```
$gradiant-background-dark-theme: linear-gradient(45deg, #1696b6, black, #1696b6);
```

Syntax : background-color: linear-gradient(angle, color1, color2);

For Transparency you have to select color code with opacity is better By using RGBA color code

Comment: Thank you, it's close but still not the same UI that I am looking for

Comment: Could you explain how this solves the problem - and perhaps put a runnable snippet showing it working into your answer (for me it doesn't make the fading in-out go in the top-bottom direction).

Comment: I  add a snippet code I hope this can be helpful